# Event handler on jQuery object

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

I am trying to bind custom events to a jQuery object, but they will not fire.

Example:

```
environment = new function(){
this.events = $();
};

environment.events.on('preloader_done', function(){
    console.log('environment event handler');
});

environment.events.trigger('preloader_done');

$(document).on('preloader_done', function(){
    console.log('document event handler');
});

$(document).trigger('preloader_done');
```

In the example above, only the event bound to the document fires. See jsfiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/ymhp5c8k/

I cannot find any information to tell me why this won't work.

I know that I can create a JavaScript object and then bind the event through jQuery like so:

```
environment = new function(){
    this.jsobject = {};
};

$(environment.jsobject).on('preloader_done', function(){
    console.log('jsobject event handler');
});

$(environment.jsobject).trigger('preloader_done');
```

But I would like to know if anyone has an explanation for how I could just set it up as a jQuery object and then call it directly without having to wrap it in jQuery every time.

Comment: I don't know the reasons, but you can change your first code snippet to:  `this.events = $({});` and then you get both events.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to create a jQuery object in your constructor

```
environment = new function(){
    this.events = $({}); // Here
};

environment.events.on('preloader_done', function(){
    console.log('environment event handler');
});

environment.events.trigger('preloader_done');
```

That should do the trick.

Comment: Yes, this did the trick, I should have created the object as $({}) instead of $()